# How do I put into a resume if I left/fired under probationary period

Tags: resume, cover-letter, probation

I would like to know if it is a good idea to put on my résumé a job I had for two or three month and for which I was fired or resigned from during the probationary period.

If so, how do you include it on your résumé or cover letter? If not, would it make me look like a liar if they found out?

Would it be good if I leave it out because it is not related to the new job I am seeking?

I am fresh grad by the way.

Answer (score 1):

It'd definitely look like you're lying if they find out. I would suggest put it on your resume, because otherwise it looks like you were doing *nothing* for 3 months. Instead you approach it at a different angle. Just say you tried the job out and didn't like it and ended up leaving due to a difference of opinions.

The employer isn't stupid, they'll probably know what that means. It's not what you/your previous employer did, it's how you handle it that'll define you.

Comment: Leaving it out is not lying - the resume is *your* document to showcase information *you* want to present to the employer. It would be lying to omit it from a question such as "Please give details of your employment/education for the last 3 years". Particularly as a fresh grad, I doubt a 3 month gap in employment would be remarked upon - sometimes it takes a while to find a job you like, and if your parents are happy to feed you then why rush into something? See my answer here for a more in depth discussion: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/54465/28766

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you which way you want to go.

1. If you choose to include the job, you'll have to disclose why you left. In this cae, say you weren't a good fit and leave it at that. Not being a good fit is not ideal but it's better than leaving under an ethical cloud or being fired for cause. Most probably, a lot better.
2. You can choose not to disclose the job. It's unlikely they'll find about that job and if they ever find out, simply say that you weren't a good fit and if that's the truth, their investigation reaches a dead end. A three-month gap in a resume is nothing remarkable, not in this economy and peobably,not for young people starting out their careers.

Comment: You could also say you didn't think your experience there was relevant to the job.

Answer (score 0):

If it was only a 2-3 month job, I wouldn't disclose it. Especially, if it was during a probationary period. This will make you look bad, as if there's a possibility that you will skip out on them. 
Besides, how will they find out if you don't tell them?!

Comment: If this leaves a gap in your CV, how do you then address it?  It would not be wise to lie about it.  Just be up front that you worked there but don't give any information until asked.  Then you can respond similarly to the suggestion given by Prinsig in their answer.

Comment: @JaneS 2-3 month is not much of a major gap, however people do need time to look for a job. Sometimes it is difficult to land a job. Graduating doesn't necessarily mean youre going straight into a job the very next day.

Comment: Or, he can go by Prinsigs suggestion. Me, personally, I wouldn't disclose it. It may cause a red flag to the employer/HR who is viewing his resume, and may make them go on to the next resume without him even knowing that he's been overlooked.